# A Space just for an App

Tags: spaces

Is there a way (perhaps using a third-party app) to make one of my Spaces permanently locked to a single app (in this case, TextEdit)?

I want to have all my TextEdit windows and nothing else in one Space, at all times.  I never want TextEdit to open windows anywhere besides my TextEdit-dedicated Space.

Answer (score 1):

In 10.7 and up, you can assign apps to Desktops. To assign an app, Control+click the app's Dock icon, navigate to `Options` and then choose to assign it either to `All Desktops`, `This Desktop` or `None`.

**All Desktops** assigns the app to be open on whatever Desktop you switch to. If you have it open on Desktop 1, and switch to Desktop 2, it will appear to not have moved.

**This Desktop** assigns the app to a specific Desktop, and force it to always open there. This is the option I would try to accomplish your goal.

**None** is the default setting, and leaves the app unbound by any Desktop-specific rules.

Comment: Unfortunately this seems to be broken in Mountain Lion.  I don't see the assign to desktop option on any of my dock menus.  Here's an article with other people experiencing this: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4138506?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: Be sure that you have more than one Desktop open to start with, otherwise you won't see the option to assign an app - given that there's only one Desktop. Try adding another one and then repeating the steps above.